Migrate from CMSMasters Content Composer for default WordPress
I need to export posts from a website built on CMSMasters Content Composer, and import them into classic or Gutenberg Wordpress.
I was not able to do this because export contains cmsmasters shortcodes. Example of the shortcode is below.
[cmsmasters_row data_shortcode_id="leobcm1hzv" data_padding_bottom_mobile_v="0" data_padding_top_mobile_v="0" data_padding_bottom_mobile_h="0" data_padding_top_mobile_h="0" data_padding_bottom_tablet="0" data_padding_top_tablet="0" data_padding_bottom_laptop="0" data_padding_top_laptop="0" data_padding_bottom_large="0" data_padding_top_large="0" data_padding_bottom="50" data_padding_top="0" data_bg_parallax_ratio="0.5" data_bg_size="cover" data_bg_attachment="scroll" data_bg_repeat="no-repeat" data_bg_position="top center" data_color="default" data_bot_style="default" data_top_style="default" data_padding_right="3" data_padding_left="3" data_width="boxed"][cmsmasters_column data_width="1/1" data_shortcode_id="0coa8ubqfr" data_animation_delay="0" data_border_style="default" data_bg_size="cover" data_bg_attachment="scroll" data_bg_repeat="no-repeat" data_bg_position="top center"][cmsmasters_text shortcode_id="9kdz1ni0ul" animation_delay="0"]

Textual post content is here.

[/cmsmasters_text][/cmsmasters_column][/cmsmasters_row]

Is there some way to export / convert this into something meaningful and importable to a default classic or Gutenberg WordPress?
